# Extracting data values from a textbox within a frame?

Tags: excel, userform, vba

In Excel I'm attempting to extract the data from the textbox that I've dynamically created within the frame. As seen in the code below, the textbox in which the names are `gogo1`, `gogo2` and `gogo3` respectively have been created. I would like the information entered into these textboxes to be pasted onto `sheet1` when the okay button is pressed. However, I cannot seem to pull any data that was entered into these textboxes and `sheet1` remains blank after the okay button is clicked.

```
Private Sub showCOL_Click()
Dim number As Integer
Dim gogo(1 To 3) As String

For number = 1 To 3

  Set first = UserForm2.Frame1.Controls.Add("forms.textbox.1")

With first
.Name = "gogo" & number
.Width = 30
.Height = 20
.Left = 36
.Top = 20 * number

End With

Next number


End Sub`


Private Sub ColnProceed_Click()

If UserForm2.Frame1.Name = "gogo2" Then
MsgBox gogo2.Value


End If
```

Comment: Typically to read a textbox's value you would use `TextBox1.Text` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are setting up three text boxes, but then checking the name of the frame that contains them in your click handling function. I believe you want to check if the name of the TextBox is "gogo2", not the Frame that groups them.

For now, if you just want to test to see what the values are in the 2nd text box, use:

```
MsgBox (Me.Controls("gogo2").Value)
```